# WebLogic, The code of method _jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit

Tags: java, jsp, weblogic, weblogic12c

In Web Logic We are having an error in JSP execution as below .

**Error below**

```
The code of method _jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit
<Script language="javascript">
^-----------------------------
</Script>
--------^

   at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag$InsertHandler.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:921)
   at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:460)
   at jsp_servlet._userinterface._pages._templates.__tilesbasepage._jsp__tag20(__tilesbasepage.java:1454)
   at jsp_servlet._userinterface._pages._templates.__tilesbasepage._jspService(__tilesbasepage.java:653)
   at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:35)
   Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

> 

I cant xchnage the code as it is in production. Like : Include to JSP:Include.

What Configuration do i need to change in Weblogic?
Any Help will appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: You don't have much choice. You either have to revert to whatever prior version of whatever JSP engine you were using that can compile that JSP page acceptably, or else reduce the code in the JSP page. This is a Java error, not a JSP or WebLogic configuration issue.

Comment: @EJP, we were using Jdeveloper and WebLogic earlier and it was not having an issue. But as we have tried with eclipse we are facing the issue now.

Comment: Is anybody has a solution?